# Adding images to toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add an image in a Top Level window in python, however I can't seem to get it working.

I've tried using canvases and following some other steps on stack overflow. One thing I haven't tried is using class, **init** and self, but I don't really understand that, and hoping I can acheive my thing without the use of self. and stuff like that :D.

```py
  def pika():
    def close():
        win.destroy()
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry("150x150")
    win.title("I CHOOSE U")
    yellowb = Label(win, bg = 'yellow', fg = 'yellow', padx = 100, pady = 100)
    yellowb.pack()
    poke = PhotoImage(file = "pika.gif")
    pika = Label(image = poke) # REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE IT NO WORKEY
    pika.grid(row = 0, column=1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    button = Button(win, text = "Close", command = close) 
    button.place(x=49, y=130)
```

Heres the main windows code

```py
win = Tk()
win.geometry("290x200")
win.title('Error')
text1 = Label(win, bg= "Cyan", fg = 'Teal', padx = 50, pady = 75, text = '#hash error',
              font = ('Times', '40', 'bold'))
text1.place(x=win.winfo_width() / 2, y=win.winfo_width() / 2)
button1 = Button(win, text = 'green', command = green)
button1.place(x=40, y=160)
button2 = Button(win, text = 'blue', command = blue)
button2.place(x=90, y=160)
button3 = Button(win, text = "red", command = red)
button3.place(x=130, y=160)
button4 = Button(win, text = 'yellow', command = yellow)
button4.place(x=170, y=160)
button5 = Button(win, text = "orange", command = orange)
button5.place(x=229, y=160)
eggs = PhotoImage(file = "pika.gif")  
eggpic = Button(win, image = eggs, bg = 'Cyan', fg = 'Cyan', command = pika)
eggpic.place(x=100, y=20)
def close():
    win.destroy()
closebut = Button(win, text='close', command = close)
closebut.place(x=0, y=0)
```

When I click a button and it opens a new windows the bg of the windows is yellow and everything as intended, however the image doesn't appear on the windows, and a white box the size of the image appears in the main tk window.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGPc4.jpg

Comment: I'm very new to tkinter, so I don't really know to use self. and it looks very scary.

Comment: instead of `def close(): win.destroy()` and `command=close` you can use only `command=win.destroy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two problems:

---

**First:** Every widget needs parent. If you don't use it then `tkinter` assigs widget to main window.

And you have this problem in `Label(image = poke)` because you forgot `win` in

```
 pika = Label(win, image=poke)
```

This is why you see rectangle in main window instead of toplevel window.

---

**Second:** There is bug in `PhotoImage`. `Garbage Collector` removes it from memory when it is created in function and assigned to local variable. And then you can see empty image.

You have to assign `PhotoImage` to global variable or assign to other widget in function.

Popular solution with assigning to other widget:

```
poke = PhotoImage(file = "pika.gif")
pika = Label(win, image=poke)
pika.photo = poke # <-- assign PhotoImage to other widget too
```

More: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)